# Mouse cylinder behaviour (dual-screen config)

Tags: lua, mouse, multiple-monitors, awesome-wm

I've already asked a question about this in [Unix & Linux SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/452909/cylinder-2-screens-config-with-xrandr) and I so actually use xdotool.

The idea is that the mouse goes at the left of the left screen when it reaches the right of the right screen and vice versa.

But I recently saw the [mouse.coords table](https://awesomewm.org/apidoc/libraries/mouse.html#coords) in the awesome API, so I'd like to give up xdotool to set mouse coordinates as do xdotool with this possibility.

I suppose I should add a signal to the root to know when the mouse is on the edge, but I don't konw how to do this...

Comment: Sorry, but awesome does not provide a signal for when the mouse cursor is moving on the root window

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Uli. I hoped there was another solution with a fewer consumption in CPU resource than xdotool...

Comment: Maybe it is possible with a 1px width wibox on the left side of the left screen and another one on the opposite side on the right screen ? I then capture mouse::enter signal ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I give a try to my idea, and it works. Here's the code for my right wibox :

```
s.myjumpbox = awful.wibar({
      position = "right",
      screen  = s,
      width   = 1,
      opacity = 0,
      ontop   = true,
      -- bg      = beautiful.noir
})                                                                  
s.myjumpbox:connect_signal("mouse::enter", function(w)              
      mouse.coords {
          x = 2 ,
          y = mouse.coords().y
      }
      end
)
```

**Edit :** add Uli's suggestions

Comment: If you have a compositing manager, you can make that wibar even fully transparent (.opacity = 0). Also, I suggest to add .ontop = true.